# How to add colour for the columns and rows in excel file in java?

Tags: java, colors

Am working on a application to read the values from database and store it in a excel file .
Now i need to add different color to the different columns and rows in the excel sheet .

Please help me in this .

Thanks in advance .

```
 /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package excelproject;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;

/**
 *
 * @author rajagopal
 */
public class ExcelProject {

    private static Connection con;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/excelproject", "root", "root");
            Statement st = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from empdetails");
            HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
             HSSFCellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();

            ArrayList lis = new ArrayList();
            DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_hh.mm.ss");
            String timeStamp = format.format(new Date());
            String Excel = "Employee_Records_" + timeStamp;
            HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet(Excel);
            HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short) 0);






            rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("Serial Number");
            rowhead.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue("Employee Name");
            rowhead.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue("Address");
            rowhead.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue("Contact Number");
            rowhead.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue("Email");
            int i = 1;
            while (rs.next()) {
                HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) i);

                row.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(Integer.toString(rs.getInt("id")));
                row.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(rs.getString(2));
                row.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue(rs.getString(3));
                row.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue(Integer.toString(rs.getInt(4)));
                row.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue(rs.getString(5));
                lis.add(rs.getString(2));
                System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
                i++;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j <= lis.size() - 1; j++) {
                ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery("select * from empdetails where name ='" + lis.get(j) + "'");
                while (rs1.next()) {
                    HSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet(rs1.getString(2));
                    HSSFRow rowhead1 = sheet1.createRow((short) 0);
                    rowhead1.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("Serial Number");
                    rowhead1.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue("Employee Name");
                    rowhead1.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue("Address");
                    rowhead1.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue("Contact Number");
                    rowhead1.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue("Email");
                    HSSFRow row1 = sheet1.createRow((short) 1);
                    row1.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(Integer.toString(rs1.getInt("id")));
                    row1.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(rs1.getString(2));
                    row1.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue(rs1.getString(3));
                    row1.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue(Integer.toString(rs1.getInt(4)));
                    row1.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue(rs1.getString(5));
                }
            }

            String filename = "c:\\ExcelFile_" + timeStamp +".xls"; 
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            wb.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
            System.out.println("Data is saved in excel file.");
            st.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: How are your writing data to excel file? Are you using POI?

Answer (score 4):

from http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CustomColors
(tested, it works)

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) 0);
HSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short) 0);
cell.setCellValue("Default Palette");

//apply some colors from the standard palette,
// as in the previous examples.
//we'll use red text on a lime background

HSSFCellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.LIME.index);
style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

HSSFFont font = wb.createFont();
font.setColor(HSSFColor.RED.index);
style.setFont(font);

cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

Comment: Hi people i tried all the above methods nothing is working out for me . can anyone help me in this .

Comment: As I mentioned above, I tested the code and it is working. Maybe if you can share your code with us we can help further.

Comment: you tried to get a reference to your cells and set their style accordingly right? because In your code there are no references to the cells.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on POI API: http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/index.html

Cell has method `setCellStyle(CellStyle style)`. `CellStyle` has multiple methods that deal with color of different parts of cell (background, border, font etc).

Comment: You also have to set fill pattern.